# Updating a field based on location field and most recent date fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to using Access and SQL, I am trying to create a database that tracks water usage at different properties.
Currently the method used to do so is to get a meter reading and record the value. This goes into table `Meter Reading` that has 4 main fields: `Property`, `Meter`, `Date`, `Reading`.

I would like to add 5th column for `Last Reading`. Ideally this column would do an Update and set `Last Reading` to the prior reading of the meter.

Example.

```
Property  Meter     Date          Reading   Last Reading
1         A         2/2/2015      4518      1X
2         B         2/2/2015      1258      2X
1         A         3/2/2015      4595      3X
```

What I would like to do is in the `Last Reading` filed to tell me when the meter was last read so in the spot of `3X` that would update to show `4518` as that was value the last time that  property `1`, meter `A`, was read. I could then easily do a math field to get the difference.

I have tried

```
Update [Meter Reading}
Set [Last Reading]= Reading
Where Date=Max
```

It would just copy the Reading Value into the Last Reading so it was not helpful.
I Have also tried doing

```
Update [Meter Reading]
Set [Last Reading]=(Select Reading
```

*this is where I am having trouble I haven't been able to get a good selection down for how to select the correct property,meter, and date to chose the right reading. 
I dont know if this is even possible but any help would be welcome, Thanks.

Comment: One idea was a correlated subquery `Update [Meter Reading]
    Set [Last Reading]= (SELECT Reading FROM [Meter Reading] r 
                         WHERE r.Property = [Meter Reading].Property
                           AND r.Meter = [Meter Reading].Meter
                           AND r.[Date] =(SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [Meter Reading] r1 
                                          WHERE r1.Property = r.Property
                                            AND r1.Meter = r.Meter 
                                            AND r1.[Date] < [Meter Reading].[Date]))`

Comment: When i tried this it gave me the "Operation Muse use an Updateable query" Error, does any one have ideas where this went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar through VBA where you open a recordset and sort in a particular order so you can loop through the data and update each record with the value from the previous record. I can't promise it's pretty or efficient, but it gets the job done. And I'd personally concatenate the property & meter since the combo seems to be your unique identifier? That's just me.

```
Public Function GetLastReadingByMeter()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
Dim strMeter As String, intReading As Integer

DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 9999

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from your_table_name order by property_meter, date", dbOpenDynaset)

rs.MoveFirst
strMeter = rs.Fields("property_meter").Value
intReading = rs.Fields("Reading").Value
rs.Edit
'If you want the first row's last reading equal to itself this line below does it (retrofit from my original dates), else you could set this to zero
rs.Fields("LastReading").Value = rs.Fields("Reading").Value
rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
Do Until rs.EOF
    If strMeter = rs.Fields("property_meter").Value Then
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("LastReading").Value = intReading
        rs.Update
        intReading = rs.Fields("Reading").Value
    Else
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("LastReading").Value = rs.Fields("Reading").Value
        rs.Update
        strMeter = rs.Fields("property_meter").Value
        intReading = rs.Fields("Reading").Value
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is just what I needed to get everything else working. I also took your advice on concatenating the property and meter fields and it stream the table more for me.